# Selenium - Can click, getText, etc. on an element except hover

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm at a complete loss on this one.  We have an `li` element that has a single a element under each.  They have no javascript, nor anything unusual about them.

However, trying to hover over one is proving to be impossible!  I can click, get text, scroll to, any other action on any of these, but for 3 of the 20 I can NOT do a hover.  There are 20 list elements and I can hover over all except 3 of them (elements 5, 10 and 15).  I've tried using the li element, using the a element under the li element, many other solutions.

In every case, selenium finds the element and can interact with it in every way except hovering.  Any suggestions?  Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="level1-all-departments" style="display: block;">
<li data-parent="0" id="31447" class="selectedLinkBold">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/holiday.html" aria-expanded="true">Holiday &amp; Seasonal</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31356" class="">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/appliances.html" aria-expanded="false">Appliances</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31357" class="">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/auto.html" aria-expanded="false">Automotive &amp; Tires</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31358" class="">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/baby-kids.html" aria-expanded="false">Baby, Kids &amp; Toys</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="557612" class="">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/clothing-handbags.html" aria-expanded="false">Clothing, Luggage, &amp; Handbags</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31359" class="">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/computers.html" aria-expanded="false">Computers</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31360">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/electronics.html" aria-expanded="false">Electronics</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="252601">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/funeral.html" aria-expanded="false">Funeral</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31363">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/furniture.html" aria-expanded="false">Furniture &amp; Mattresses</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31361">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/gift-cards-tickets-floral.html" aria-expanded="false">Gift Cards, Tickets &amp; Floral</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31362">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/grocery-household.html" aria-expanded="false">Grocery &amp; Household</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31365">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/health-beauty.html" aria-expanded="false">Health &amp; Beauty</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31366">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/home-and-decor.html" aria-expanded="false">Home &amp; Kitchen</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31364">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/hardware.html" aria-expanded="false">Home Improvement</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31367">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/jewellery-fashion.html" aria-expanded="false">Jewellery, Watches &amp; Sunglasses</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31368">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/office-products.html" aria-expanded="false">Office Products</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31369">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/patio-lawn-garden.html" aria-expanded="false">Patio, Lawn &amp; Garden</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31489">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/pet-supplies.html" aria-expanded="false">Pet Supplies</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="31370">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/sports-fitness.html" aria-expanded="false">Sports &amp; Fitness</a>
</li>
<li data-parent="0" id="439601">
    <a href="https://this.website.com/view-more.html" aria-expanded="false">View More Categories</a>
</li>
```

Here is the code I'm using to successfully hover (I stuck with the index because that removed the most other potential issues, however, I've tried about every other way to identify the element):

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='level1-all-departments']//a[4]/..")
private WebElement listElement;

Actions aAction = new Actions(wDriver);
aAction.moveToElement(listElement).build().perform();
```

Thanks
-Greg

Comment: Can you include the code you are running to attempt to hover over these elements? This will help us track down the issue more easily.

Comment: I've added the relevant snippets.

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, I will mention that I've had some very strange results using `moveToElement` to hover over elements in a list. If there's a way you can use Javascript instead of `Actions` class, this might solve your issue.

Comment: You are allowed to post your own solution that you have discovered as an answer to this question, and mark it as accepted. Since I do not actually know the Javascript you used to perform the hover, I don't want to take credit for the answer, but it should still be posted as an answer so other users can see the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get this working using javaScript hover as suggested by Christine.

```
        mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover',true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
        ((JavascriptExecutor) wDriver).executeScript(mouseOverScript, element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the below code to hovering using text of element and WebDriverWait.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Baby, Kids &amp; Toys')]")))
actionChains.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```